# Why my app is not running on VS 2012 express for windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I installed Windows 8 RP and VS 2012 Express for windows 8 in my system.Previously i did sample apps and executes it's successfully.But Suddenly app is not running while debug the application shows only"Build is started"but not showing output.

while putting break point in my app does not coming to solution.Why  metro app is not  running in VS 2012 express?
does not show any errors doesn't show any output only showing build started message.

please help me..

Below is screen shot...
[image]

Only Showing that message always  not giving any output....

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Windows 8 Release Preview, you need to be running Visual Studio 2012 **Release Candidate**, which you can download here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29931